# jQuery connect accordion with tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion, connect

I would connect accordions with tabs similar to the jQuery's official demo [here](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists-through-tabs) but instead of lists, using accordions...it's possible? Can someone provide me a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [Accordion | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) demo.

You should be able to combine tabs with accordeons if you use

```
$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   $( "#accordion-1" ).accordion();
   $( "#accordion-2" ).accordion();
});
```

and HTML structure like this

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="accordion-1">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                Tab 1 - Section 1
                </p>
            </div>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                Tab 1 - Section 2
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <div id="accordion-2">
            <h3>Section 1</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                Tab 2 - Section 1
                </p>
            </div>
            <h3>Section 2</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                Tab 2 - Section 2
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i try do implement this code in the example but it doesn't work...i tink i need to modify something but i don't know where...

Comment: tank-you again :) u know how to drop an accordion into other tab?

Comment: ok i'm trying to move an accordion from tab1 to tab 2, can you help me?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. I didn't know you were using sortables.

Comment: Sorry, next time i will be more specific :)